# Find non-hexadecimal formatted data

Tags: hive, hex

I am trying to write a query in hive to find the rows that are not in hexadecimal format. I used RLIKE which retrieves the rows that are in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `NOT RLIKE`:

```
select col from table where col not rlike '^[0-9A-F]+$'; --apply your hexadecimal pattern
```

For both upper and lower case use this pattern: `'^[0-9a-fA-F]+$'`